# Mobile CSS Won't Display

Tags: iphone, css, mobile

I'm trying to teach myself how to make a mobile version of a website, so I started off with something basic.

I have the following code

```
<body> 
You are using...
<p class="mobile">
Mobile
</p>

<p class="desktop">
Desktop
</p> 
</body>
```

with the CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px)  
{    
     p.desktop {
         display:none;
     }
}

    p.mobile {
        display:none;
    }
```

Basically, I want either "mobile" or "desktop" to display depending on which device you're using. When I navigate to the site on my desktop it says "desktop", so that seems fine.
But when I do so on my iPhone it still says desktop.

I have tried increasing the max-width to 640px which is the iPhone 4S' resolution. But I still have no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think that's how you differentiate between mobile and desktop devices. have you tried different style sheets? <link rel="handheld" src=""> for example ?

Comment: @Jessedc Uh, media queries are exactly how you differentiate between mobile and desktop devices.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No I have not, as I read that mobile browsers are too advanced and do not identify themselves (therefore, do not respond) to the "handheld" tag.
I also read that this is one way to do it. http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/11163/mobile-device-trick/p1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default viewport on an iOS device is somewhere around 1000 pixels. You may notice when you pull up your test page that it doesn't look like it's a 320px wide - it's way zoomed out.

You need a viewport `meta` tag in your page `head` that sets the viewport width to that of the device:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Once in place, you'll find your @media query works nicely (although you need a `p.mobile { display: block; }` bit to make the "mobile" text show up).